# Where do I pay tax - UK or Malta?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, foreign-income, malta

I'm a UK company director but am considering a move to Malta where I will become resident and work remotely, with occasional visits back to the UK. My wages (and dividends) will be paid into a UK bank account but where do I pay tax - UK or Malta?

Comment: "My wages (and dividends) will be paid into a UK bank account"  Why?  If you're sensibly escaping to a no-tax jurisdiction, do that.  Close all bank accounts, everything, in the UK. Never have anything to do with them again. (If you're trying to "edge it" and "officially" get tax benefits, while "really" still Being a Brit ... just forget it, save your time, it will never work.)

Answer (score 3):

You usually have to pay tax on your UK income even if you’re not a UK resident and wages are included on which you have to pay tax.

Malta has a [double taxation agreement with UK](http://www.mfsa.com.mt/pages/viewcontent.aspx?id=196)  so you don't have to pay tax in both places. So you can pay your taxes in UK and that covers all. If in doubt you can visit a tax adviser or contact HMRC for any further clarifications.

[Source on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/tax-uk-income-live-abroad/overview)